# Operand data type varchar is invalid for multiply operator

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am finding "CPR" a function from based on different aspects of a bond.

Our current formula is this:

```
SELECT All
a.[CUSIP NUMBER],
CPR,
a.[POOL PREFIX],
a.[POOL NUMBER],
a.[POOL TYPE],
a.[CURRENT MM],
a.[CURRENT YY],
a.[ISSUE MM],
a.[ISSUE DD],
a.[ISSUE YY],
a.[MATURITY MM],
a.[MATURITY DD],
a.[MATURITY YY],
a.[SELLER NAME],
a.[SELLER STREET],
a.[SELLER CITY],
a.[SELLER STATE],
a.[SELLER ZIP],
a.[ORIGINAL WA COUPON],
a.[SD SECURITY TYPE],
a.[SD INTEREST RATE],
a.[SD POOL PREFIX],
a.[SD POOL NUMBER],
a.[CURRENT WA COUPON],
a.[CURRENT BALANCE],
a.[ORIGINAL WA MATURITY],
a.[CURRENT WA MATURITY],
a.[PASS THRU RATE],
a.[CURRENT FACTOR],
b.[CURRENT FACTOR] as AprilFactor,
b.[ORIGINAL BALANCE],
MonthlyRate,
Payment,
InterestPayment,
Principle,
ScheduledFace,
PreviousFace,
ScheduledFactor,
SMM
INTO March2013CPR
FROM dbo.mbs022013 a
JOIN dbo.mbs032013 b ON a.[CUSIP NUMBER] = b.[CUSIP NUMBER]
CROSS APPLY (Select (a.[PASS THRU RATE]*.01)/12) CA(MonthlyRate)
CROSS APPLY (Select (a.[CURRENT BALANCE] * ((MonthlyRate)/((1-(1/power(1+ MonthlyRate, a.[CURRENT WA MATURITY]))))))) CA2(Payment)
Cross Apply (Select a.[CURRENT BALANCE] * MonthlyRate) CA3 (InterestPayment)
Cross Apply (Select Payment - InterestPayment) CA4 (Principle)
Cross Apply (Select a.[ORIGINAL BALANCE] * a.[CURRENT FACTOR]) CA5 (PreviousFace)
CROSS APPLY (Select PreviousFace - Principle) CA6(ScheduledFace)
Cross Apply (Select ScheduledFace/a.[ORIGINAL BALANCE]) CA7 (ScheduledFactor)
Cross Apply (Select 100 * (1-(b.[CURRENT FACTOR]/ScheduledFactor))) CA8(SMM)
Cross Apply (Select (1-(power(1-SMM/100,12)))*100) CA9 (CPR)
WHERE a.[CURRENT WA MATURITY] != 0 and a.[CURRENT BALANCE] != 0
```

We calculated through cross-apply's so that we could post the entirety of the portfolio into a new table with CPR values for each bond. This function has worked for several months of data, but for this month it simply returned:

```
Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 49
Operand data type varchar is invalid for multiply operator.
```

This is calculating the function for March. The file for March uses information from the February file and the March file. However, I don't believe there is a problem in either file, as the function is correct for the February file, which uses January and February, and for the April file, which uses April and March data.

Line 49 is the line that says:

```
Cross Apply (Select a.[ORIGINAL BALANCE] * a.[CURRENT FACTOR]) CA5 (PreviousFace)
```

Any ideas how to fix? :-D

UPDATE:

Here is some example data:

```
CUSIP NUMBER     Original Balance     Current Factor     Pass Thru Rate  Current Balance
31416HAB1        00000325972000       0.19556008         04.500         00000063747109
31416HAB1        00003749061700       0.11487645         05.000         00000430678890
31416HAC9        00002164121900       0.15490762         05.500         00000335238974
31416HAD7        00000274716900       0.22204878         06.000         00000061000552
31416HAE5        00018198400200       0.10905233         06.000         00001984577976
```

Current WA Maturity ranges from 0-360.

Comment: That would happen if both of those fields were of a character datatype, check the table schema

Comment: Before you post, try to create the simplest query that reproduces the problem.  Post example data along with your query.

Comment: basically like @AlexK. has said. You are trying to multiply a varchar ant that cant happen. If it looks like a number but is stored as a varchar you will have to wrap the statement in a CAST or CONVERT to Float

Comment: @Dev N00B Thanks for the help! I'll try CAST, as CONVERT to Float did not solve it.

Comment: As amusing as this has been, neither side is contributing to the overall health of SO. Mods have cleaned comments twice. I suspect a third visit might result in temporary suspensions

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on @Alex K's and Dev n00b comments, you appear to have character data in your [Original Balance] as evidenced by the leading zeros. The data type precedence allows for implicit conversion from character types (char/varchar/nchar/nvarchar) to number types (int/float/decimal).

Somewhere, in your data it appears you have a non-numeric value in that column. If CAST fails, CONVERT will fail as well. You might need to find the incorrect rows and correct the data. Otherwise, if you can ignore those values and since you're on SQL Server 2012, you can take advantage of the [TRY_CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) function like

```
Cross Apply (Select TRY_CONVERT(bigint, a.[ORIGINAL BALANCE]) * a.[CURRENT FACTOR]) CA5 (PreviousFace)
```